# i18n t does not exist on type NuxtApp

Tags: vue.js, internationalization, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, vue-i18n

I'm using @nuxtjs/i18n plugin with nuxt 3
When i try to get 't' method from $i18n plugin on useNuxtApp it says:

TS2339: Property 't' does not exist on type 'ExportedGlobalComposer & NuxtI18nRoutingCustomProperties & I18nRoutingCustomProperties'.

[image]

although the method works correctly, it's only typescript error

where can be the error and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to **convert** your images of text into actual text? Likely useful: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting) Can you please read about [the problems with images images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to convert your images of tables into markup tables? See [/editing-help#tables](/editing-help#tables) for how.

Comment: Same problem here: `Property 't' does not exist on type 'ExportedGlobalComposer & NuxtI18nRoutingCustomProperties & I18nRoutingCustomProperties'`. Did you find a fix?

Comment: I am still trying to figure that out